# How do I pass the address of a c++ method in win32 app to a c# method with Action delegate parameter method

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a *win32* application using a *C# library*.

The *C# library* has a method where the `Action<T>` delegate is a parameter as shown:

```
public NetSocket(Action<int, int, string> action)
```

I have a ref class in the win32 application with a method that matches the Action delegates signature.

How exactly do I pass this method as the **Action** parameter in the `NetSocket` method listed above?

---

Ben your solution seem to work but there was a compile error on matching the `System:Sting`^ input parameter of the action delegate method in the **win32 application** to the `String` input parameter of Action delegate in the **C#** code. The Action delegate in the c# code uses a `String` as an input parameter and the Action delegate method in the win32 code tries match using a `System::String^` to match it but that does not work.

> // win 32 app - `void ServerClass::ActionMethod(int iCommand, int iClientIndex, System::String^ message)`
>
> // win32 app  -server = `gcnew NetSockets::NetSocket(gcnew Action(this,&ServerClass::ActionMethod));`
>
> // csharp  - `public NetSocket(Action<int, int, string> action)`

Is there some marshaling method I need to use to match `System::String` used in the win32 code to string used in the C# code? Am I passing the `System::String` wrong or is something else have to be done? What must I do to match the `System::String^` message parameter to the string parameter?
Thanks

---

Been correction I tried your solution and it gave the following error:

> 1  error C3352: `'void ServerClass::ActionMethod(int,int,System::String ^)'` : the specified function does not match the delegate type `'void (void)'`

---

@Ben : Getting close. Now when I compile the code using you solution i get an internal compile error as shown:

> error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\msclr\marshal.h 49 1 win32project

The code is compiled in Visual Studio 10 where the Framework 3.5 is used and not 4.0

I checked the line where the internal compile occurs and the error happens here in
line 49 in the marshal.h file:

```
_size = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_THREAD_ACP, WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, _pinned_ptr, _str->Length, NULL, 0, NULL,NULL);
if (_size == 0 && _str->Length != 0)
{
    throw gcnew System::ArgumentException(_EXCEPTION_WC2MB);
}
```

I guess the error happens because the `String::String^` input parameter in the c++ code is not being marshaled probably to the c# code, or the other way around.

I'm not sure what I need to fix the c++ side of the code or the C# side of the code.
Any idea?

I guess could just make a c++ dll and have the c# library import the library and call a method in the c++ dll, and then have the win32 application load the c++ dll, but that would seem to be odd to have a library load a w++ dll when the c++ dll used the c# library as a reference.

---

I checked the line where the internal compile occurs and the error happens here
line 49 in the marshal.h file.

```
_size = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_THREAD_ACP, 
                              WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS,
                              _pinned_ptr, 
                              _str->Length, 
                              NULL, .
                              0, 
                              NULL,
                              NULL);
if (_size == 0 && _str->Length != 0)
{
    throw gcnew System::ArgumentException(_EXCEPTION_WC2MB);
}
```

I guess the error happen because the String::String^ input parameter in the c++ code is not being marshalled probably to the c# code, or the other way around.
Not sure id I need to fix the c++ isde of the code or the C# side of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a native C++ function, use [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx)

If you're using C++/CLI, which it sounds like (and you should retag the question), you want something along the lines of:

```
NetSocket(gcnew Action<int,int,String^>(this, &ServerClass::ActionMethod))
```

Comment: @steve please don't add code to comments. Add it as an edit to the question.

Comment: Been correction I tried your solution and it gave the following errorError 1 error C3352: 'void ServerClass::ActionMethod(int,int,System::String ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (void)'

Comment: @steve: The HTML formatter had eaten your generic parameters.  I'll fix my answer to match.

Comment: -1, `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` throws when given a generic delegate type.

Comment: @ildjarn: If true, that would be a bug, and anyway it turned out that @steve is using C++/CLI.  But the question as originally written said `Action` (non-generic) and nothing about C++/CLI.

Comment: @BenVoigt : It is true, and is documented directly on the page you linked to: "*The GetDelegateForFunctionPointer method has the following restrictions: Generics are not supported in interop scenarios.*"