# the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (void)'

Tags: c#, visual-c++, interop, marshalling

```
Error C3352: 'void ServerClass::ActionMethod(int,int,System::String ^)' :
```

> the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (void)' D:\westside\NetSockets\win32project\Win32.cpp   70  1   win32project

In short a win32 application uses a C# library. When the win32 application calls a constructor method in the C# library the error above shows up. Below is the code. I am not sure what I am missing.

**win32 application code**

header file

```
public ref class ServerClass
{
NetEvents::NetEventArgs^ args;
NetSockets::NetSocket^ server;
public:
void ActionMethod(int iCommand, int iClientIndex, System::String^ message);
void StartServer();
};
```

source file

```
void ServerClass::ActionMethod(int iCommand, int iClientIndex, System::String^ message)
{

}

void ServerClass::StartServer()
{   
server = gcnew NetSockets::NetSocket(gcnew System::Action(this, &ServerClass::ActionMethod1));
}
```

**C# library code**

```
namespace NetSockets
{
public class NetSocket
{
    Action<int,int,string> actClient;

    public NetSocket(Action<int, int, int> action)
    {

    }

    public NetSocket(Action<int, int, string> action)
    {
        this.actClient = action;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Steve: No one is going to email you directly.  You have to check back here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass the address of a c++ method in win32 app to a c# method with Action delegate parameter method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486272/how-do-i-pass-the-address-of-a-c-method-in-win32-app-to-a-c-method-with-action)

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Action` delegate is a delegate type with no parameters that returns void.

As the error message says, your function doesn't match that.

You need to use a different delegate type, such as `Action<int, int, string>`.